# Generation of peaks with EMG

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I need to build a function like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQywM.png)
with the following parameters:

A - peak area

h - peak height

w - peak width in the middle

b/a -  asymmetry factor

I have a function described in the [file](http://docdro.id/a6jDDmz), and I'm trying to use it to get the peak with the necessary parameters, fitting the the tau and sigma, but error(the square of the sum of the error for each parameter in percent) is still to big.
Does anyone know a function that can build a peak with given parameters?
P.s. sorry for my "russian" english

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.